Run ShellExecute() Command Directly From PS1 File
An example, PowerShell Script:
If ( (fltmc).Count -eq 3 ) {
    $A   = "CreateObject(`"Shell.Application`").ShellExecute"
    $VBS = "$A `"powershell.exe`", `"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file $PSCommandPath`", `"`", `"RunAs`", 1"
    $VBS > "$Env:temp\ga.vbs"
    & "$Env:temp\ga.vbs"; exit 0
}
pause

the script above create the VBS file to $Env:temp\ga.vbs, then call it & ....
How to Run ShellExecute directly from the PS1 file, without creating vbs file on $Env:Temp?

ShellExecute() is not unique to VBScript; it's a standard Windows API function available in Shell32.dll, so a better question would be how to access that from PowerShell, directly – trying to use VBScript is just going the long way around.
The Start-Process cmdlet in PowerShell can be used to run a program with a custom verb specified:
Start-Process ... -Verb RunAs


Question edited. i mean using ShellExecute(), not start-process

@Mr.Key7: The point was, though, that Start-Process is how you normally call ShellExecute() from PowerShell; that's literally the Windows API that PS internally uses.

I just learned other ways than start-process. Thanks.

Found this way. Without making temporary vbscript file.
if ( (fltmc).Count -eq 3 ) {
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    $AL = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file `"$PSCommandPath`""
    $Shell.ShellExecute("powershell.exe", "$AL", "", "RunAs", 1)
    exit 0
} else {'A.D.M.I.N'}

pause

